# Python, thread and gobject

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I am writing a program by a framework using pygtk. The main program doing the following things:

1. Create a watchdog thread to monitor some resource
2. Create a client to receive data from socket
3. call `gobject.Mainloop()`

but it seems after my program enter the Mainloop, the watchdog thread also won't run.

My workaround is to use `gobject.timeout_add` to run the monitor thing.

But why does creating another thread not work?

Here is my code:

```
import gobject
import time
from threading import Thread

class MonitorThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print "Watchdog running..."
        time.sleep(10)

def main():

    mainloop = gobject.MainLoop(is_running=True)

    def quit():
        mainloop.quit()

    def sigterm_cb():
        gobject.idle_add(quit)


    t = MonitorThread()
    t.start()

    print "Enter mainloop..."

    while mainloop.is_running():
        try:
            mainloop.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

The program output only "Watchdog running...Enter mainloop..", then nothing.
Seems thread never run after entering mainloop.

Comment: What more do you expect? With the above code, I expect those two things to be printed once each.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you post some code? It could be that you have problems with the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).

[Your problem solved by someone else :)](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/01/python-gstreamer_threading_and_the_main_loop/). I could copy-paste the article here, but in short gtk's c-threads clash with Python threads. You need to disable c-threads by calling gobject.threads_init() and all *should* be fine.

Comment: I'm glad you added a short hint in the answer as the link is now dead.

Answer (score 2):

You have failed to initialise the threading-based code-paths in gtk.

> You must remember two things when
>   using threads with PyGTK:
>
> 1. GTK Threads must be initialised with gtk.gdk.threads_init:

From http://unpythonic.blogspot.com/2007/08/using-threads-in-pygtk.html, copyright entirely retained by author. This copyright notice must not be removed.

You can think glib/gobject instead of pygtk, it's the same thing.